# Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException: 'ORA-00942: table or view does not exist' error with EntityFramework Core v3.1

Tags: oracle, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to build my first .NET project in Visual Studio 2019 that uses EntityFramework Core v3.1 library in order to retrieve the records from an Oracle database table.

The sample project that I've created for this has the following configuration:

1. it's a ASP.NET Core MVC App (Model-View-Controller) project that uses .NET Core 3.1
2. contains the following third party nuget packages: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 3.1.14, Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore 3.19.110

The 'Startup' class is defined as follows:

```
public class Startup
  {
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseOracle(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyConnectionString"));
        });

        services.AddScoped<ITestRepository, TestsRepository>();

        services.AddControllersWithViews();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

'MyConnectionString' has been specified properly(I'm 100% sure that it is no mistake here) in the 'appsettings.json' file.

I've defined a 'TestsRepository' class in order to retrieve the 'Test' records from the database as follows:

```
public class TestsRepository : ITestRepository
{
    public readonly AppDbContext _appDbContext;

    public TestsRepository(AppDbContext appDbContext)
    {
        _appDbContext = appDbContext;
    }

    public IEnumerable<TEST> AllTests
    {
        get
        {
            return _appDbContext.Tests;
        }
    }
}
```

The 'AppDbContext' is defined as follows:

```
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }

    public DbSet<TEST> Tests { get; set; }
}
```

The 'TEST' class is defined as follows:

```
public class TEST
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string NAME { get; set; }
}
```

The 'HomeController' class is defined as follows:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ITestRepository _testRepository;

    public HomeController(ITestRepository testRepository)
    {
        _testRepository = testRepository;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var tests = _testRepository.AllTests.ToList();
        return View();
    }

    public IActionResult Privacy()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
    public IActionResult Error()
    {
        return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
    }
}
```

The 'ITestRepository' class is defined as follows:

```
public interface ITestRepository
    {
        IEnumerable<TEST> AllTests { get; }
    }
```

When I'm running the project, the following exception is thrown when executing the statement:

```
var tests = _testRepository.AllTests.ToList();
```

from 'HomeController' -> 'Index' action:
Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException: 'ORA-00942: table or view does not exist'.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong because the 'TEST' table exists with the proper fields/columns in the specified Oracle database from the 'MyConnectionString'.

Please help me with this issue!

Comment: I don't read .net and so could not make out exactly where you supply the credentials for connecting to the database, nor exactly how you specified the table name. But I do know that  'ORA-00942: table or view does not exist' is definitive. Most likely you specified the table name without the owner (SELECT * FROM MYTABLE  instead of SELECT * FROM SCOTT.MYTABLE) and the table belongs to an owner other than the one you connected with.

Comment: The connection settings which includes the credentials, the database server address, etc. are specified in the MyConnectionString in the following format: “DATA SOURCE=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=ORCLCDB.localdomain)));USER ID=dummy; Password=dummy;” and I'm 100% sure that it is correct because I'm using with successs in another .NET project. Also, if I try to modify it by specifing a wrong db server address I get another exception error that the remote db server cannot be reached, so I'm pretty sure that it is correct..

Comment: Also, I'm not doing any SQL statements in my code as 'SELECT * FROM MYTABLE' or so because this shall be done automatically by EntityFramework when querying automatically the datatabase if I'm using LINQ expressions on the entities defined in the AppDbContext, like 'Tests', etc

Comment: The fact that your connect string "works" (you successfully connect to the correct database) is fine and well, but that alone has nothing to do with ora-00942.  _"this shall be done automatically by EntityFramework"_.    Well, _somewhere_ you have to actually specify the table you want to query.  And it _WILL_ come down to either (1) you don't qualify the table name with the owner, and the table is not in the connected user's schema, or (2), you did qualify the table name with the owner, and (2a) the table doesn't exist or (2b) the connected user doesn't have privileges on the table..

Answer (score 0):

To find this table in Oracle database, specify your db shema name and table name for your class:

```
[Table(name:"TBL_TEST", Schema ="USER1")]
public class TEST
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string NAME { get; set; }
}
```